# Creating mySQL columns via php with foreach hits limit

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML form submitted with a "post" method, after which I use a foreach to  check if I have a column name matching the $_POST name; if not, I create that column. I then store in each appropriate column the $_POST data.

It all seemed to work fine, until I tried submitting the whole form (about 500 different entries). The php function stops at 449 created columns. Of those, the last 6 columns return a "null" result (instead of the submitted $_POST info), and the 20 before that only have 1 on 2 correctly aved $_POST data.

When I check with print_r($_POST) I can confirm that all the data is transmitted. I have tried changing in the php_ini the memory limit or max_execution_time with no success.

This is my foreach php code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        //$allKeys = array_keys($_POST);
        //$keyName=$allKeys[$i];
        $key=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $key);
        $value= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, stripslashes($value));

        $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table LIKE '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $key)."'");
        $exists = (mysqli_num_rows($result))?TRUE:FALSE;
        if(!($exists)) {
           $add=mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE $table ADD (".$key." VARCHAR(65500))");           
        }       

        $query="INSERT INTO $table 
        ($crmNumberKey,$key) 
        VALUES 
        ('$crmNumberValue','$value')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        $key='$value'";

        mysqli_query($link, $query);


        unset($_SESSION['profileInProgressCrmNumber']);
        unset($_SESSION['profileInProgressAccountName']);
        unset($_SESSION['profileInProgressAccountCity']);
        unset($_SESSION['profileInProgressAccountRep']);                                        
    }
```

Can someone explain why I can't create the remaining 50 columns and completely update them and the currently created last 30 or so?

Thanks,

Comment: You do not want to create dynamic columns. That typically is a sign of a model that should be rethought or redesigned.

Comment: ... or it's Magento ...

Comment: **WARNING**: Don't mix `mysqli` and the deprecated, broken `mysql_query` function. That `i` is important, and your code here may not work because it's using the wrong back-end driver. Using `mysqli` in object-oriented mode helps avoid simple mistakes like this.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: @arkascha I am doing this to avoid creating the columns one by one. Once my HTML form is done and database matches, i intend to take out that function.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have not hit the maximum column limit (4096), you are hitting the maximum row size for the table:

> Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes

[This may be of more assistance as it has great discussions surrounding the efforts behind this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/too-many-columns-in-mysql)